# json array extraction in ANSI SQL using Presto

Tags: arrays, json, presto

Here is the problem I am running into:
 I have data elements for a column "xyz" in my presto table in json with array format as mentioned below:

```
col1 | col2
a    | {"fruits": ["apple", "banana", "orange"]}
b    | {"fruits": ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grapes"]}
```

I need the data in the below format:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4  | col5
a    | apple|banana|orange | null
b    | apple|banana|orange | grapes
```

or

Any example on how to read array elements in json would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_array_extract_scalar()` function with respective index values for each column to extract the each column value as strings

```
SELECT col1,
       json_array_extract_scalar(col2,'$.fruits[0]') as col2,
       json_array_extract_scalar(col2,'$.fruits[1]') as col3,
       json_array_extract_scalar(col2,'$.fruits[2]') as col4,
       json_array_extract_scalar(col2,'$.fruits[3]') as col5
  FROM tab
```

You can also replace `json_array_extract_scalar` with `json_array_extract` in the above query to get each column in the JSON format.

Comment: @Piotr: Thanks a lot for your reply but I am getting the flowing error: (SYNTAX_ERROR) line 3:2: Unexpected parameters (row(fruits array(varchar)), varchar(9)) for function json_extract

Comment: yes @AAN we need a slight conversion with the function name `json_array_extract_scalar` should be used instead of `json_extract_scalar`.